# Disable caching in Javax xml transformer

Tags: java, xml, xslt

In this article (https://www.ahoi-it.de/ahoi/news/java-xslt-memory-leak/4830) it is explained that Javax xml transformer caches XML contents to its internal HashMap for later use.

This is my issue: I am reading XML messages from activemq and if something fails, I retry to convert them again using Javax XML transformer and send them to certain endpoint. The problem is that eventually my Docker container restarts because it runs out of memory.

What I would like to do is disable caching, unfortunately, after 3 hours of research I still have no idea how to do so.

I have a utils class with static methods and this is how my Javax XML Transformer looks like:

```
public static String getTransformedXml(Object input, String transformerFileName)
        throws IOException, TransformerException {
    ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(transformerFileName);
    InputStream xsltStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(xsltStream);
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    transformer.setErrorListener(new XsltTransformerErrorListener(transformerFileName));

    Source text = new StreamSource(new StringReader(XmlUtils.encode(input, input.getClass())));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

    transformer.transform(text, result);

    return result.getWriter().toString();
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting the transformation of the one XML file to the other into its own Thread ?

Comment: You could try running it under Saxon instead of the default JDK transformation engine. Also (but perhaps not related), if you are running this transformation repeatedly then you should only create the TransformerFactory and Templates object once, and then create a new Transformer for each transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the TransformerFactoryImpl :
`TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);`